# Can Terminators without human tissue talk?

Tags: the-terminator-series

As we all know, in the first Terminator movie a T-800 model came from the future. It came disguised with human tissue and it can talk like a human.

So my question is: can T-800 Terminators and other (endoskeleton) models talk when they *aren't* covered in human tissue? I never saw a Terminator without human tissue talking in the Terminator films.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify if you mean just those with hard-metal endoskeletons or whether you're also interested in those comprised of liquid metal.

Comment: @Valorum, i'm Mostly interests in endoskeletons Models..

Comment: @RANSARA009 - I don't see it as a dupe. THe one marked is asking how the Terminator typically makes speech. This one is asking if *it can continue to do do without skin*.

Comment: Not really a dupe.  Partial, perhaps, but not worth closing, in my opinion as the OP of the other question.

Comment: From the dupe: "This raises the question of whether the bare metal Terminators (see picture below) can speak, and if so, whether their mouths move when they speak."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Yes they can.

In [Terminator: Salvation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_Salvation) we see an (unskinned) T-800 Endoskeleton speaking during the fight sequence between Kyle, John and an endo in the Terminator Factory. It imitates Reese to lure John to it.

[image]

> **VO:** *Connor. Connor help. Help! Connor it's Kyle! Help!*
>
> [John Rounds the corner only to come face to face with the
> endoskeleton Terminator. He's been tricked]

Note that at least the last couple of words are said ***with the Terminator in full view.***

---

Similarly, we see an unskinned T-888 speaking in [Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles - The Turk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator:_The_Sarah_Connor_Chronicles)

[image]

> **Dr. Fleming:** *I have a camera. Would it be alright if I...*
>
> **Terminator:** *Move away*
>
> [The terminator then proceeds to remove its clothing revealing that it has no skin]

Comment: Is the terminator talking, or playing a recording through a speaker somewhere on it's body?

Comment: @daft - I'd assume it has some kind of vocaliser/speech synthesiser in or near its throat. If the sound emitted came from elsewhere in its body, it would sound less human.

Comment: @daft - it's definitely not a **recording**. Kyle doesn't say those words (or any combination of those words) in front of the Terminator.

Comment: Of course, this movie has been ejected from canon.

Comment: @DCShannon - Well, it's been undone by future events, as has every other Terminator property, including the original 'The Terminator'.

Comment: Also, I believe that Cromartie (The Sarah Connor Chronicles) did some talking during a fleshless period he was going through. Of course, he's technically a T-888, not a T-800 as the question specified.

Comment: @StephenCollings - Cheers. I've edited that in.

Answer (score 1):

While the liquid metal models can create any base-structure needed for speech, the T800 models may still need the organic part to generate sound naturally (to help infiltration capabilities). While theres no definitive statement about this, we can consider some logical and probable issues:

Arguments if favor of yes they can speak without bio-components:

- Technologically, it is easier to produce a speech synthesizer than it is to reproduce all the organic components needed to generate the voice.
- See the deleted [army staff meeting scene](https://youtu.be/kayFrIR-Qfw). The T has a strange accent. Skynet is experimenting on how to design Infiltrators for maximum infiltration efficiency (giving them sweat, breath, etc), and a staff member said it can fix that, which implies they can technologically tweak the accent/voice.

Arguments in favor of no, they cannot speak without bio-components:

- A speech synthesizer would not be required for standard non-infiltration combat models as commands could be transmitted via wireless
- Given the probably lower number of infiltrators compared to pure combat models, it would be resource-inefficient to include a speech synthesizer in all models (does not exclude including it in Infiltrator models only though)

My conclusion would be that if they would be able to speak, the organic part would definitely make them sound more human.

Comment: Another argument in favor of not relying on bio-components is the fact that terminators can imitate other people's voices.

Comment: Indeed. I agree.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**
The T-1000 and T-X do not contain living tissue and both speak in the films.
They may do so by vibrating an internal metallic membrane, but creating a steel speaker that sounds natural is a lot easier than time travel, so it should be trivial for Skynet.

Comment: Although the OP probably hasn't been entirely clear (leading to some ambiguity) I believe the question relates to **hard-metal endoskeleton terminators**, not those that are made from liquid metal.

Comment: I agree that it does seem he may have intended to ask that, and Valorum's answer is even clearer about the T800 model, but since the question said "other models" I figured it was worth pointing out that most of the humanoid models down lack any human tissue and speak just fine.

Answer (score -2):

No, they cannot **speak**.

[Speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech) –Wiki

> In linguistics (articulatory phonetics), manner of articulation describes how the tongue, lips, jaw, vocal cords, and other speech organs are involved in making a sound make contact.

I personally doubt the possibility of even a super-computing AI being capable of constructing an audio reproduction system, into such a small package as a humanoid nonetheless, that's able to trick me into believing it's a human being. For that you need organic matter: lips, tongue... *"everything"*

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but although an AI on its own can't necessarily sound human, 3D printing technology is making tremendous progress in building lifelike prosthesis. A human-like yet artificial voice synthesiser is no longer beyond the bounds of reality. Also, AI has already progressed enough to successfully fool humans into believing  they are chatting with a real human online. So, yeah, with regards to your personal belief...the future is here (almost).

Comment: Alas, you forgot to watch all of the Terminator films including the really crappy one.

Comment: Real world information is edifying, but generally not the whole story when it comes to in-universe answers, as Valorum's answer demonstrates.

Comment: A simple small speaker (or maybe another part which is able to oscillate at a controlled frequency, you can even make some sounds with stepper motors) would be enough.

Comment: The TX may beg to differ that it needs organic matter.

Comment: Using a dictionary definition of a word and using it to disprove a proposition, ignoring the intent is fallacious.   That might work in high school debate but not not as a means of invalidating what the OP intends to ask.

Comment: @Valorum - You forgot to read the tags on the question.